# Trying to add a protocol to a Class signature in swift

Tags: swift, protocols, storekit

I'm trying to create an in-app purchase in swift. In my class signature, I have the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate,   
SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver{
```

However, I get an error message: type "ViewController" does not conform to protocol: SKPaymentTransactionObserver

I've read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html and [Conform to protocol in ViewController, in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092346/conform-to-protocol-in-viewcontroller-in-swift)

The SKSoreProductViewControllerDelegate works fine. What am I missing, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you implemented the required methods in your class?

`paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` and `paymentQueue:updatedDownloads:` are required methods and you will get a warning if they are not implemented.

Comment: i have added both  `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:`  and `paymentQueue:updatedDownloads:` but error is same

Answer (score 5):

`SKPaymentTransactionProtocol` has these methods:

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) 
@optional func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, removedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)
@optional func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: NSError!)
@optional func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!)
@optional func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedDownloads downloads: [AnyObject]!)
```

The first is a required method that your class has to implement in order to conform to the protocol. Add it to your ViewController and the error will disappear.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate,   
SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver{
    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!){/*...*/}
    /*...*/
}
```

Comment: Should be     `func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)` in Xcode beta 4.

Answer (score 2):

For swift use this:

```
public func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) { /* */ }
```

Instead of this:

```
public func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) { /* */ }
```