# Does not conform to protocol SKPaymentTransactionObserver

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am trying to implement in app purchases in a `Swift` app, of a consumable in-app purchase, with product ID `productID`

**Research**

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235822/in-app-purchase-in-swift-with-a-single-product), I learned about the basic pattern for in app purchases, and tried to adapt it, like so. I do not need to use the NSUserDefaults method of having the app remember if a purchase is made, as I am handling that with a different solution.

**Code**

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
     viewDidLoad() {
         //Unimportant stuff left out
             product_id = "productID"
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
         }

        @IBAction func thisISTheButtonToTriggerTheInAppPurchases(sender: AnyObject) {

            if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
            var productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_id!);
            var productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>);
            productsRequest.delegate = self;
            productsRequest.start();
            print("Fetching Products");
        }else{
            print("can't make purchases");
        }

        }
     func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
        print("Sending the Payment Request to Apple");
        var payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment);

    }

    func productsRequest (request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {

        var count : Int = response.products.count
        if (count>0) {
            var validProducts = response.products
            var validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
            if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
                print(validProduct.localizedTitle)
                print(validProduct.localizedDescription)

               print(validProduct.price)
                buyProduct(validProduct);
            } else {
                print(validProduct.productIdentifier)
            }
        } else {
            print("nothing")
        }
    }


    func request(request: SKRequest!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        print("Error Fetching product information");
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)    {
        print("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{


       switch trans.transactionState {
            case .Purchased:
                print("Product Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                break;
            case .Failed:
                print("Purchased Failed");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                break;



            case .Restored:
                print("Already Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions() 


            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

**Error**

> Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'SKPaymentTransactionObserver'

I researched this error a bit, and sources like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588531/trying-to-add-a-protocol-to-a-class-signature-in-swift) suggest that such an error is due to not having required functions.

[According to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/), `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` is the only one required, but I seem to be implementing that. A possible theory of mine is that I am not implementing it correctly - if true, how do I fix that?

**Expected Behavior**

The app presents, and if given favorable user input, performs the IAP with the ID `productID`.

Thanks for helping, and let me know if you need any more information!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very simple. The error is about SKPaymentTransactionObserver. Its only [required method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SKPaymentTransactionObserver/paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:) is:

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue,
    updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])
```

The signature for *your* method doesn't match that:

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, 
    updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)
```

...so it isn't the same method, so you don't conform.