# Swift: How to implement CVCalendar

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, protocols

I am trying to implement the CVCalendar cocoapod (https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar) and in the instructions it says:

'CVCalendar requires an implementation of two protocols CVCalendarViewDelegate and CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate, please implement both.'

I dont understand how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make your class a subclass of CVCalendarViewDelegate and CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CVCalendarViewDelegate, CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate {
```

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-ID195

Take a look at the answer to this question: [Conform to protocol in ViewController, in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092346/conform-to-protocol-in-viewcontroller-in-swift/24092444#24092444)

Answer (score 0):

As per Oliver's answer you need to add protocols to your class declaration :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate,CVCalendarViewDelegate {
```

You also need to add these two functions to comply with the new protocols:

```
func presentationMode() -> CalendarMode{
    return .monthView
}
func firstWeekday() -> Weekday{
    return .monday
}
```